# Large images cropped by page boundaries while creating pdf of web page in Microsoft edge browser

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, printer, microsoft-edge

I wanted to create a PDF of [this web page](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling) so that I can open it one the tablet and read / annotate. But it is not getting converted correctly. I tried saveral printers, Chrome's own Save to PDF, Microsoft's print to pdf printer driver, print2pdf printer driver. But all are printing images in extra large size so much so that they are cropped by page boundaries as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

How can I get neat pdf of this page?

Comment: Tried several online webpage to pdf conversion sites. [One of them](https://webtopdf.com/) gave really good output.

Comment: Firefox has an excellent Print to PDF feature, which includes scaling, fitting images to page, choice of "paper" size, etc.